# Assign shortcut keys in Java for onClick function

Tags: java, function, onclick

I have a `onClick: function(event)`. All I want is to assign a shortcut key for this onClick event. When the link is clicked execute a shortcut key, for example: ctrl+D.

Thank you.

Comment: You can set a "shortcut key" on several swing objects (like JButton) with `setMnemonic(...)`. You then can trigger the action with alt+key.  I guess you can also define shortcuts with strg+key.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In a simpler way, you wouldn't actually try to add a `shortcut` for your `onClick()` event. What you would actually want is to add a `KeyListener` to a specific component (basically the same component on which you've added the `MouseListener`) and you would try to perform the same action as you're doing when the user clicks on the component.

["How to Write a Key Listener"](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/keylistener.html) might be a good place to start to understand more about `KeyListeners`.

Another useful link for you might be this: ["How to Use Key Bindings"](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html)

Answer (score 0):

you say `execute a shortcut key`. do you want to simulate keystrokes?

if this is what you want take a look at `java.awt.Robot` http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Robot.html